# Grouping regular expressions in C#

Tags: c#, regex, validation, date

I'm trying to validate dates in C#.

I need to check for the following formats:

```
dd/mm/yy
dd/mmm/yyyy
dd-mm-yy
```

The below expression throws an exception:

```
@"^(*\d{2}+[-\])+([\w{3}]|[\d{2}])+(\d{2,4})$"
```

Kindly point out the error in the expression.

Comment: Kindly point out the error in the expression

Comment: Is your variable a `DateTime` or `string`? I would use `DateTime.TryParseExact` overload that takes `string[]` as a formats instead of regex.

Comment: you can also create an array of regular expressions to loop over while validating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question about the regex, there are several issues.

- The critical is the issue with `(*` in the beginning (already pointed out by vks)
- Another critical issue is with another misplaced quantifier `+` in `d{2}+`
- And one more issue is that you have placed alternatives into a character class. `([\w{3}]|[\d{2}])+` means "select from 2 alternatives: 1) `\w`, `{`, `3`, or `}`, 2) `\d`, `{`, `2` or `}`, 1 or more occurrences".

So, your regex in .NET regex flavor will look like:

```
^(\p{N}{2})([/-])(\p{L}{3}|\p{N}{2})\2(\p{N}{2,4})$
```

See [demo on RegexStorm that supports .NET regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%5Cp%7BN%7D%7B2%7D)(%5B%2F-%5D)(%5Cp%7BL%7D%7B3%7D%7C%5Cp%7BN%7D%7B2%7D)%5C2(%5Cp%7BN%7D%7B2%2C4%7D)%5Cr%3F%24&i=12-12-1234%0D%0A12-feb-1234%0D%0A12-12-12%0D%0A12-feb-12%0D%0A12%2F12%2F1234%0D%0A12%2Ffeb%2F1234%0D%0A12%2F12%2F12%0D%0A12%2Ffeb%2F12&o=m)

And a more generic version is `^([0-9]{2})([/-])([a-zA-Z]{3}|[0-9]{2})\2([0-9]{2,4})$`.

**However**, if you want to validate `DateTime` values written as strings, you need to `DateTime.TryParseExact` them. Here is an example that meets your requirements:

```
var fmts = new[] { "dd/MM/yy", "dd/MMM/yyyy", "dd-MM-yy"}; // Allowed formats
DateTime dt;
var valid1 = DateTime.TryParseExact("13/02/15", fmts, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
// true
var valid2 = DateTime.TryParseExact("10/Apr/2012", fmts, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
// true
var valid3 = DateTime.TryParseExact("23-02-10", fmts, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
// true
var valid4 = DateTime.TryParseExact("01-30-15", fmts, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
// false
```

Comment: Please consider also upvoting the answer if you found it useful (the up arrow on the left).

Answer (score 2):

```
^(\d{2})([\/-])(\w{3}|\d{2})\2(\d{2,4})$
```

Guess you need this.

```
    `^(*`

       ^^
```

This quantifier is giving the error as it has nothing to quantify.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tS1hW2/2